# Hangman -- with a surfeit of for loops

Tags: java, hangman

How can I improve this code so I do not use so many `for` loops in this?

```
public class Hangman {
   private String secretWord;
   private String disguisedWord ="";
   private String guessedLetters = "";
   private int numberOfGuesses = 0;
   private int numberOfIncorrectGuesses = 0;

   Hangman(String secretWord){
     this.secretWord = secretWord;
     for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){
       this.disguisedWord += "?";
     }
   }

   public String getSecretWord() {
        return secretWord;
   }

   public String getGuesses() {
        return guessedLetters;
   }

   public String getDisguisedWord() {
        return disguisedWord;
   }

   public int getGuessCount() {
        return numberOfGuesses;
   }

   public int getIncorrectGuessCount() {
        return numberOfIncorrectGuesses;
   }

   public boolean isFound() {
        if (secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase(disguisedWord)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
   }

   public boolean makeGuess(char guess) {

        for (int i = 0; i < guessedLetters.length(); i++){
            if (guess == guessedLetters.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("You have already guessed that letter.");
                return false;
             }
        }

        guessedLetters+= guess;
        String tempString = "";
        numberOfGuesses++;
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                if (guess == secretWord.charAt(i)){
                    tempString += guess;
                } else {
                    tempString += disguisedWord.charAt(i);
                }
        }
        if (!tempString.equalsIgnoreCase(disguisedWord)) {
                disguisedWord = tempString;
                return true;
        } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Guess!");
                numberOfIncorrectGuesses++;
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        Hangman hangman = new Hangman("pirate"); // enter secret word as a string

        while (hangman.isFound()== false){
            System.out.println("The word is: " + hangman.getDisguisedWord());
            System.out.println("Guess a letter or type 'guesses' to see your guesses.");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("guesses"))
                {
                    System.out.println(hangman.getGuesses());
                }
                else
                {
                    hangman.makeGuess(input.charAt(0));
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The secret word was: " + hangman.getSecretWord());
            System.out.println("It took you " + hangman.getGuessCount() + " guesses to get the correct answer.");
            System.out.println("You had " + hangman.getIncorrectGuessCount()+ " incorrect guesses.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll assume you meant improve (i.e. make better) as opposed to improvise (i.e. make up as you go along).  As for your question... you're not using any arrays as it is.  So I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get rid of these statements in the code : 
for (int i = 0; i < guessedLetters.length(); i++)

Comment: The question is *why* - *why do you want to avoid loops*. Please **[edit]** your post to clarify.